# How To Get Refresh Token from Microsoft Graph API

Tags: php, azure-ad-graph-api

I am having difficulty get a refresh token.  For some reason it seems that the Graph API is not recognizing my offline_access scope.  Here is my PHP code:

```
$oauthClient = new \League\OAuth2\Client\Provider\GenericProvider([
  'clientId'                => "id",
  'clientSecret'            => "secret",
  'redirectUri'             => "redirect",
  'urlAuthorize'            => "https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxxx/oauth2/v2.0/authorize",
  'urlAccessToken'          => "https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxxx/oauth2/v2.0/token",
  'urlResourceOwnerDetails' => '',
  'scopes'                  => 'MailboxSettings.ReadWrite offline_access'
]);
```

From my redirect script, I get a code but not a refresh token.  Shouldn't I get both or am I not understanding how it works.

Comment: First get code with this format `https://login.microsoftonline.com/YourTenant.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/authorize? client_id=YourClientId &response_type=code &redirect_uri=https://www.getpostman.com/oauth2/callback &response_mode=query &resource=https://graph.microsoft.com &state=12345` with this code request for refresh token like this format method type POST `client_id:YourClientId scope:https://graph.microsoft.com/User.ReadWrite.All redirect_uri:https://www.getpostman.com/oauth2/callback grant_type:authorization_code client_secret:YourClientSecret code:Paste your code here`

Answer (score 0):

You were using [OAuth 2.0 code grant flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v1-protocols-oauth-code).

In this flow, you will firstly make a request to the authorize endpoint. The authorize endpoint will return an authorization_code to you. Then you will make a POST request with the authorization_code to the token endpoint to get an access token and refresh token.

[image]

I checked the tutorial for [OAuth 2.0 Client - Authorization Code Grant](https://github.com/thephpleague/oauth2-client#authorization-code-grant), the sample contains the logic for getting access token and refresh token. You can refer to the relevant code.

[image]